# VueJs this.method is not a function? How to call a method inside another method in Vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to call a method from another method and for this I've used this. But my console is causing me an error.

How to call a method inside another method in Vuejs?

## code

```
 methods: {
     searchLocations: function() {
         var address = this.search
         var geocoder = new window.google.maps.Geocoder()
         geocoder.geocode({
             address: address
         }, function(results, status) {
             if (status === window.google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                 this.buscarLojas(results[0].geometry.location)
             }
         })
     },
     buscarLojas: function(center) {
         console.log(center)
     }
 }
```

## console:

> this.buscarLojas is not a function

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have an anonymous call back function that overwrites `this` keyword, you can either assign `this` to another variable `ref` before using it in your anonymous function:

```js
methods: {
    searchLocations: function () {
      var address = this.search
      var geocoder = new window.google.maps.Geocoder()
      var ref = this
//    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function (results, status) {
        if (status === window.google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          ref.buscarLojas(results[0].geometry.location)
        //^^^
        } else {
          alert(address + ' not found')
        }
      })
    },
    buscarLojas: function (center) {
      console.log(center)
    }
}
```

Or use an arrow function:

```js
methods: {
    searchLocations: function () {
      var address = this.search
      var geocoder = new window.google.maps.Geocoder()
      geocoder.geocode({address: address}, (results, status) => {
      //                                                     ^^
        if (status === window.google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          this.buscarLojas(results[0].geometry.location)
        } else {
          alert(address + ' not found')
        }
      })
    },
    buscarLojas: function (center) {
      console.log(center)
    }
}
```

Comment: The second option is better

Comment: @Imre_G Yeah. I generally prefer the second option as well.

Comment: @Psidom Could you explain more about this? `You have an anonymous call back function that overwrites this keyword`. Your answer worked, thank you.

Comment: Vue js proxies properties in `data` and `methods` so you can access them in other methods; But if you define another function inside your method like your `callback` function, the function will have [its own `this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) and in which case `this` keyword doesn't refer to the vue instance anymore.

Comment: This question/answer helped me because I used jquery within a vue-method that overwrote ```this```. Maybe this information is helpful for anyone. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use arrow function for callback

```
geocoder.geocode({address: address}, (results, status) => {
    if (status === window.google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        this.buscarLojas(results[0].geometry.location)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I know there is an answer here already, but this can also be a convenient alternative

```
methods: {
 var self = this;   //this line will take control of **this** which can be use later
 searchLocations: function() {
     var address = self.search
     var geocoder = new window.google.maps.Geocoder()
     geocoder.geocode({
         address: address
     }, function(results, status) {
         if (status === window.google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
             self.buscarLojas(results[0].geometry.location)
         }
     })
 },
 buscarLojas: function(center) {
     console.log(center)
 }
```

}