# this.$emit is not a function inside file reader onload

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I know about lexical scope that `this` keyword is pointing to the window and not Vue

But how do I make it point to Vue?

What I am trying to do is get csv data and parse it, I'm using d3 to parse the data it's working fine, I am just unable to emit the event with the data because of the scope issue

```
    async loadcsv(element){
        let reader = new FileReader();
        let file = element[0].file

        reader.onload =  async function (e){
            const data = e.target.result;
            let csvParsed = await d3.csvParse(reader.result);
            let collection = []
            csvParsed.forEach(function (element) {
                collection.push({
                    id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000),
                    country : element['Country'],
                    email : element['Email id'],
                    poi_serial : element['Serial'],
                    status: "New"
                })
            });
            // Not working, shows it's not defined
            // this.$emit('csvCollection', collection) 
        }
        reader.readAsText(file);
    },
```

Comment: That worked thanks @IbrahimZanbily, if you want you can write that in an answer and I will accept it

Comment: I'm happy it worked, you're welcome. ok I will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the `reader.onload` line to the below to keep lexical scope for the `this` keyword

```
reader.onload =  async (e) => {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the vue instance in a variable before the async function you are using like let self = this. or you can use an arrow function instead of the function you are using. see this similar question [VueJs this.method is not a function? How to call a method inside another method in Vuejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51289458/vuejs-this-method-is-not-a-function-how-to-call-a-method-inside-another-method)

Comment: Don't store `this`. Use an arrow function so `this` is bound to the `this` you would have stored.

Comment: Yes you are right, using an arrow function is cleaner